# Assume G(s) is a PRG, is the following also a PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

> Let s be a n-length binary word and not_s its negation. Let G be a PRNG with expansion 2n.
>
> 1. Prove that H1(s) = G(not_s) is also a PRG?
> 2. Prove that H2(s) = G1(s)||G2(not_s) is also PRG. Given G1, G2 are both PRGs and the || is concatenation

I honestly don't know how to make of this question as I am pretty new. But maybe you can prove it just by saying the existence of a distinguisher D which can predict the output of G(not_s) would imply that you can predict the output of G(s) too by flipping the End_output. This would imply G is no longer a PRG. so... done?

As for the 2nd part to the question – my guess here would be to choose G1 as H1 so we would have 2 normal PRGs as proven in a but the concatenation of the output string would be G2(not_s)||G2(not_s). Then we can say H2 is not a PRG but i don't know how to explain that formally?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72201/discussion-on-question-by-swedishpotato-assume-gs-is-a-prg-is-the-following-a).

Comment: Hint: if $s$ is uniformly distributed, so is $\overbar{s}$.

Comment: Although (1) is true, (2) is not. So, this is not "prove" but rather "prove or refute".